# enabling log file regardless parameters

Tags: wix, wix3.5

To write to log file, I understand that parameter /l*v with destination path must be appended to msi file. If I want log writing to happen even if parameter is not provided?

Comment: You've been given three fine answers from three well known experts.  Perhaps you should accept one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Installer v4.5+ supports the [MsiLogging property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370322%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Older versions of MSI would require setting the command-line option or using [logging policy registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369776%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I actually avoid using this property.  Windows 7 has a known defect where heap corruption causes the Shell to forget where the temp directory is.  If you try to do an uninstall from ARP it'll fail until you kill explorer and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the logging policy in system registry, and all packages will follow it in case the command line switch is not specified. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369776.aspx) for more details.